# Magento Error - Call to a member function options() on a non-object in JS.php

Tags: magento, nginx, timeout

I'm seeing this error in my PHP error log:

```
2012/07/02 15:40:34 [error] 9963#0: *140 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function options() on a non-object in "/htdocs/app/code/local/Mana/Core/Helper/Js.php on line 35" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xxx.x.xxx, server: xxx.xxx.xxx.x, request: "GET /category/subcategory?___SID=U HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fcgi-xxxxxxx.com.sock:", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.x", referrer: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x/category/subcategory"
```

I have never edited the JS.php file so can't see why this could be happening. The error occurs when an item is added to the cart. Everything seems to actually be working but the page takes 60 seconds to load (way too long) which I guess is the script timeout period. Once an item is in the cart, every page on the site takes 60 seconds to load, making the entire site unusable.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I'd really appreciate the help as the site just isn't usable like this and I can't find the cause anywhere.

Comment: Did you fix it? Share with us.